# calculation of all possible combinations.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we are given $x_1 - x_2 = 31$.
Constraints - $0 \leq x_1 \leq 45$ and $0 \leq x_2 \leq 45$.
Then we have to tell number of all possible distributions for $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: It is not possible to have $x_1-x_2=31$ if $0\le x_1\le 18$ and the same holds for $x_2$. Is something else intended?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Perhaps its $x_1+x_2=31$?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't afraid of generating functions, you can do as follows: The values of either $x_i$ can be represented by the polynomial:

$$
1 + z + \dotsb + z^{18} = \frac{1 - z^{19}}{1 - z}
$$

The ways of getting the sum $x_1 + x_2 = n$ is the coefficient of $z^n$ in the product of the above, so you want (ellipses are for terms that can't influence the result):

$\begin{align}
[z^{31}] \frac{(1 - z^{19})^2}{(1 - z)^2}
  &= [z^{31}] (1 - 2 z^{19} + \dotsb) \sum_{k \ge 0} (k + 1) z^k \\
  &= [z^{31}] \sum_{k \ge 0} (k + 1) z^k
        - 2 [z^{12}] \sum_{k \ge 0} (k + 1) z^k \\
  &= 32 - 2 \cdot 13 \\
  &= 6
\end{align}$

Here we used:

$$
(1 - z)^{-n}
  = \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{-n}{k} z^k
  = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{k + n - 1}{n - 1} z^k
$$

Answer (score 0):

In the event that the question is written correctly as being $x_1-x_2=31$ with $0\leq x_i\leq 18$ for $i=1,2$, then for all choices of $x_1,x_2$ the total $x_1-x_2$ will be at *most* equal to $18$, and could never equal $31$.  I.e. the number of choices of $x_1, x_2$ satisfying all of the conditions will be zero.

In the event that the question is written incorrectly and should have been $x_1+x_2=31$ with $0\leq x_i\leq 18$ for $i=1,2$, then by a similar argument, if $x_1\leq 12$, the largest the sum $x_1+x_2$ could be is $30$.

As such, consider each choice of $x_1\in\{13,14,\dots,18\}$.  There will be one choice of $x_2$ such that the sum $x_1+x_2$ is equal to $31$.

(*E.g. consider  $x_1=15$, then $x_2=31-x_1=31-15=16$.  No other choice of $x_2$ will do.*)

There are then six choices, (namely $(13,18), (14,17),\dots (18,13)$)

---

For a more general approach, consider the number of solutions to the problem: $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2=31\\ 0\leq x_1\leq 18\\ 0\leq x_2\leq 18\end{cases}$

by inclusion-exclusion principle on the number of upper bound conditions violated.

It will then be the number of solutions to $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2=31\\0\leq x_1\\0\leq x_2\end{cases}$ minus the number of solutions to $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2=31\\19\leq x_1\\0\leq x_2\end{cases}$, minus also the number of solutions to $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2=31\\0\leq x_1\\19\leq x_2\end{cases}$, plus again the number of solutions to $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2=31\\19\leq x_1\\19\leq x_2\end{cases}$.  The final of which trivially being zero.

Through a change of variable, this is seen to be $\left(\!\!\binom{31}{2}\!\!\right) - 
2\cdot \left(\!\! \binom{12}{2} \!\!\right) = \binom{32}{1} - 2\cdot \binom{13}{1} = 32-26=6$

---

Given the recent edit, increasing the upper bounds of each $x_i$ to $45$, the first approach I outlined seems the more useful.

Notice that for each choice of $x_1\in\{0,1,\dots,30\}$ you will have $x_1-x_2\leq 30-x_2\leq 30-0=30<31$ and so these choices of $x_1$ contribute nothing to the total.  On the other hand, each choice of $x_1\in\{31,32,\dots,45\}$ will have exactly one $x_2$ for which $x_1-x_2=31$,  namely $x_2=x_1-31$.